# Ionic does not recognize function call

Tags: ionic-framework, ngrx

I want some help with re-writing this code because it shows there is an error but the code works fine when run.

```
export function loadingReducer (state: LoadingState, action) {
    return reducer(state, action);
```

it says I should use const or class but when I use those the code won't run.

Comment: action could be typo is some ide's so u need to set a type for it like action: string or action of type any... second you are returning reducer(state, action) which isn't known if its another helper... u need to show related hings since as overall the syntax is right but must check other related things that they may be causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a linting issue rather than an actual code problem. When using `const`, are you using it like this? :

```js
export const loadingReducer = (state: LoadingState, action: Action) => {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```